# Can't use array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `Main` and a `Cars` classes, and I am trying to create an array of `Cars` and have it like this:

```java
public class Cars {

    protected String brand;
    protected int price;
    protected Cars[] list;
    Scanner keyboard;
    
    public Cars() {
        keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    
    public void carList() {
        int nv;
        System.out.println("number of cars");
        nv=keyboards.nextInt();
        Cars [] list = new Cars[nv];
        ...
    }
```

then I have this `for`:

```java
for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    list[i].brand=keyboard.next();
    list[i].price=keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

to try and fill it but I get this error:

```
Cannot assign field "brand" because "list[i]" is null
```

Can you help me pointing what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: hint:  `Cars [] list = new Cars[nv];` doesn't initialize any Car.

Comment: you create an array, but you don't put any values in it. What you are doing, is trouble comming. For each of those elements in the array, you'll create a new array, ...

Comment: At no point are you adding any object of type `Cars` into your array, at least in the code you show. Also, rethink your design. Are you aware that every object you insert in your array will in turn have an array of objects of the same type?

Comment: No, I didn't know any of this, this is just an exercise  I got in class and my teacher isn't really teaching us, just writing down solved problems on the board, so I'm mostly learning on my own, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `Cars` array, as:

```java
Cars[] list = new Cars[nv];
/* two smells here:
   1. Cars (plural) as a type, and having array of Cars objects.. that is Cars of cars;
   2. don't name arrays as list.. lists are another type.
*/
```

but you never put any `car` instance into that array.

Afterwards, with:

```java
list[i].fieldName
```

you are trying to fetch the i<sub>*th*</sub> element from the `list` array and access its field, but you have `null`s in your array (which is the default value array of reference type is initialized with), therefore, fields `brand` and `price` will not be resolved as you're accessing them on the `null` reference.

Instead, you should first create an object(s) and put that(those) into your array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new Objects in the Array before you can assign values:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++){
  Car car = new Car();
  car.brand = keyboard.next();
  car.price = keyboard.nextInt();
  list[i] = car;
}
```